# Cast to type T where I have the string name of T

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create class instance in assembly from string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433451/create-class-instance-in-assembly-from-string-name)

Using a string representation of the Type `MyClass` I want to create an instance of `MyClass` from a string representation of it.

See the comments in my code:

```
interface MyData
{
    string Value { get; }
}

class MyClass : MyData
{
    public MyClass(string s)
    {
        Value = s;
    }

    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public static explicit operator MyClass(string strRep)
    {
        return new MyClass(strRep);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MyClass inst)
    {
        return inst.Value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass inst = new MyClass("Hello World");

        string instStr = inst; //string representation of MyClass
        string instTypeStr = inst.GetType().FullName;

        // I want to be able to do this:
        MyData copyInst = (instTypeStr)instStr; // this would throw an error if instTypeStr did not inherit MyData

        // Then eventually:
        if (instTypeStr.Equals("MyClass"))
        {
            MyClass = (MyClass)copyInst;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create class instance in assembly from string name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433451/create-class-instance-in-assembly-from-string-name) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648160/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/c-sharp-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string and so on and so on

Comment: How's this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance` method

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/d133hta4(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx).

To persist your class data to string you should *serialize* your `MyClass` object to string.
To retrive your class data from string you should *deserialize* your `MyClass` object from string.

[XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) will help you

Comment: Using this would surely mean only a C# application can access it.

Comment: @Ben, no. You can store your deserialized object in file. Java application can read this file and deserialize in its own class, similar to `MyClass`.