# C# Access dictionary from different class

Tags: c#, dictionary, naudio

I've been working on a project using a dictionary, but I got a problem.
In my one wpf class (form) I create a dictionary with some stuff inside. In my second class, I want to read from that dictionary, so I've set the modifier of my dictionary to 'public'. And there is the problem. My dictionary gives the error: `CS0050: Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'Dictionary<int, CachedSound>' is less accessible than field 'LoadAudioForm.noteValue'`. Does any of you know how to fix this?

This is a part of my code of my first class:

```
public partial class LoadAudioForm : Form
{
    public Dictionary<int, CachedSound> noteValue = new Dictionary<int, CachedSound>();

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        for (int i = 36; i < 97; i++)
        {
            noteValue.Add(i, new CachedSound("E:/VirtualCarillon/VirtualCarillon/VirtualCarillon/VirtualCarillon/Audio/01/" + i + ".wav"));
        }
```

And now the second class:

```
AudioPlaybackEngine.Instance.PlaySound(LoadAudioForm.noteValue[ne.NoteNumber + (Convert.ToInt32(nVelR) * 100)]);
```

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632525/inconsistent-accessibility-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as the error says: The type of the field is less accessible than the field itself.

The field is `public` so the field's type must be at least `public` or otherwise the compiler will complain about this inconsistency.

The field's type in your code is `Dictionary<int, CachedSound>`; We know `Dictionary` and `int` are `public`, so check `CachedSound`'s access modifier and make sure it's not `internal` or `private`.

Comment: Yup, this was the problem. My CachedSound class didn't have any modifier, so I changed it to public, and that solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are accessing the `dictionary` like it is a `static` variable but it is not.

If it fits your logic, you can change the `dictionary` to be static.

```
public static Dictionary<int, CachedSound> noteValue =
    new Dictionary<int, CachedSound>();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Same error as before.